# Python win32 how to set multiple filter values into pivot table?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I have a excel pivot table created with win32 module, what i need to do is to set a specific set of 3 values into one of its filters.
I tried to set the filters into it like this:

```
pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields("Filter").ClearAllFilters()
pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields("Filter").EnableMultiplePageItems = True
pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields("Filter").CurrentPage =  ['6A', '70', '82']
```

But this seems to apply only the first value (which is '6A' in this case) into the filter.

Answer (score 0):

pt = pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields("Filter").PivotItems()

pt = [x.Name for x in pt]

for f in pt_ws.PivotFields("Filter").PivotItems():

if f.Name in pt: f.Visible == True   else: pass

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to fix the line breaks and indentation. Since Python is sensitive to whitespace, this code won't run as posted.